# Spring WebMVC: interceptor which has access to the method definition and the HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to intercept Spring Controller calls which are annotated, similar to:

```
@RequestMapping("/my/page")
@AccessRestriction(module = Module.Audit, action = AuditActions.Log)
public ModelAndView myPage() {
   // pls type teh codez
}
```

At this point I want to access both the values of the `@AccessRestriction` method, the `HttpServletRequest` object to check if the values match the restrictions and the `HttpServletResponse` object in order to send a redirect , if applicable. Being able to throw an exception might be suitable as well.

I've looked into [Interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) but they don't offer access to the method, just the handler. What are my options of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to decouple the two concerns, one to check the annotation and throw an exception, another to catch that exception and translate it into a redirect.

The first concern could be done using the [Auto-proxy facility](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-autoproxy), which would apply an AOP-style interceptor to any invocations on your controller objects. They would check for the annotation, validate the invocation, and throw a custom `RuntimeException` is the conditions are violated.

You could then have a custom `HandlerInterceptor` which checked for this exception in the `afterCompletion` method, sending a redirect via the response object if it's present.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot (!) to mention that I must have the HttpServletRequest. I need to compare values from the request with values from the Annotation. So while I completely agree with cutting out the redirect, I still need the request, which hints at MVC-specific infrastructure.

Comment: @Robert: The auto-proxy can work with request-scoped interceptors, which in turn can be auto-wired with the current request.

Comment: @Robert: You can use `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestContext().resolveReference(RequestAttributes.REFERENCE_REQUEST)` to get a thread-bound request inside an aspect.